# Hidden folder copied during unit test run on VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I've found that when running a VS2008 unit test that a hidden .svn subversion folder is copied under the Out folder that the unit test creates. This is because I've labeled a Resources folder in my unit test as "Additional File and Folder to deploy." Anybody know if you can mark a folder (in this case the .svn folder) as an exclude?

Answer (score 1):

You only can include single files or whole folders. The problem is that the deployment takes time. The less files are copied, the faster start you tests.

Alternatively you can run your tests in the solutions out folder, by disabling "deployment". But I wouldn't do it. Or you can try to copy it yourself, for instance in a method marked with [AssemblyInitialize]. You get a TestContext, which has the property TestDeploymentDir. If you don't really have to optimize it, don't do it.